Split delimited row from one table and insert columns into new table
I am using SQL Server and trying to do what I think should be an easy task. I have one table that contains a single column containing pipe delimited data like the following, the row begins and end with a pipe and uses pipes to separate "columns". The column is defined as VARCHAR(350).
|abcd | 1.234 | xyz |aaaaa|xxxxxxx|

Although I show show five "columns" here, there are a total of 26 columns. I do not want the pipes. I need to break out the values between the pipes and place into a different table. In this example abcd would be in row 1 column 1, 1.234 would be row 1 column 2, xyz in row 1 column 3, etc.
I originally tried using SUBSTRING as shown below the location of the pipes may change although the number of columns will remain the same.
INSERT INTO dbo.tblNew 
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(tempData,2,11) AS Column1,
        SUBSTRING(tempData,14,18) AS Column2
        ...
        SUBSTRING(tempData,337, 8) AS Column26
    FROM 
        #tblTemp;

In short, is there a way to split a delimited string into multiple columns on the same row of a new table?

Using relational databases for non-relational data isn't always easy... but why not use string_split?

@DaleK Well STRING_SPLIT() does not guarantee the original order of the PSV data will be maintained.

@TimBiegeleisen only pre-2022

Aside, databases have columns, not fields.

I looked into STRING_SPLIT() but it appears to put values into a new row and not the same row different columns. If that's not correct, care to share a resource I can review? I do need to maintain the order.

Yeah, that would give you rows, then you would pivot it back to columns.

See this answer which shows both (1) how to use ordinal option of STRING_SPLIT() together with PIVOT (SQL Server 2022 and later) and (2) an alternative using OPENJSON() that works with earlier SQL Server versions.

This should work with the example provided.

In the absence of a table we have to create a temp one and put the string in it
Declare a variable and make it as long as stated in the question (350 characters)
Assign the value from the temp table to a variable
Split the string into its constituent parts at the pipe delimiter and assign a unique id to each element. Rownum does this for us.
Flip the rows to columns

To make 26 columns, just add additional rows to the Flip section.
--create a temp table with the example string
CREATE TABLE #tmp (f1 VARCHAR(350));
INSERT INTO #tmp (f1)
VALUES ('|abcd | 1.234 | xyz |aaaaa|xxxxxxx|');

DECLARE @tosplit VARCHAR(350);

--Get the field containing the pipes from your table
--Replace #tmp with your table
SELECT @tosplit = f1 FROM #tmp;

;WITH split AS (
    SELECT
        value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn  --assign a unique ID to each row output
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@tosplit, '|')
    WHERE value <> ''
)

--Flip the rows to columns for each unique column identified
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN value END) AS elem1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN value END) AS elem2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN value END) AS elem3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN value END) AS elem4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN value END) AS elem5
FROM split;

Result:



elem1
elem2
elem3
elem4
elem5




abcd
1.234
xyz
aaaaa
xxxxxxx




The row_number trick isn't guaranteed to return correct results, especially when you cross apply it against the whole table.

I agree. In that case this will only apply when there are 27 pipes, ie every field is present. When the number is <27 there is no way to know which field is missing or where to map the subsequent fields.
